# how to: Rails respond_to json using exact same rabl template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I am have two actions of which renders eventually should output json using the same rabl template, but at the moment, they each have a template with their own name

dashboard.json.rabl and batch_create.json.rabl

they are the exact same, how can I specify in the batch_create template to use the dashboard's template?

Thank you!

EDIT #including controller's two actions and their rabl views

## line_items_controller.rb

```
def dashboard
  @line_items ||= LineItem.limit(1000).all.to_a
  pids = [1,2,3,4,5]
  @projects = Project.only(:id, :name).where(:_id.in => pids).to_a
  @users    = User.only(:first, :last, :role, :company_id).all.to_a
  @companies= Company.where(:_id.in => @users.map(&:company_id)).to_a
  @specs    = Spec.where(:specable_id.in => pids).to_a
    spec_ids= @specs.map { |e| e.id }
  @contact_infos = ContactInfo.where(:infoable_id.in => spec_ids).to_a    end
  gon.rabl

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
  end
end

def batch_create
  @line_items = LineItem.where(:_id.in => params[:line_item_ids]).to_a

  # else same as #dashboard
end
```

## app/views/line_items/dashboard.json.rabl SAME AS app/views/line_items/batch_create.json.rabl

```
object false

child @projects => :projects do
  attributes :id, :name
end

child @companies => :companies do
  attributes :id, :name
end

child @users => :users do
  attributes :id, :full, :company_id
end

child @specs => :specs do
  attributes :id, :style, :due_at_note
end

child @contact_infos => :contact_infos do
    attributes :info, :infoable_id
end

child @line_items do
  attributes :id, :title, :dashboard_length, :dashboard_created_at, :original_file_url, :project_id
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using this in the batch_create.json.rabl:

```
extends '<insert_object_name>/dashboard'
```

Comment: Hi TC, I tried that but but the returned object is wrapped in an array. So in my dashboard.json.rabl, it returns {"foo":"bar"}, if I do the extends 'line_items/dashboard' in my batch_create.json.rabl, I get back [{"foo":"bar"}]. Any chance you know how to exclude it being treated as an array of objects? Thank you

Comment: Could you update the question with both the rabl views and the controller actions?

Comment: Is the entire response enclosed in [] or just the line_items child?

Comment: the third the last line should be "child @line_items => :line_items do" and the entire response isn't enclosed in []